# Javascript and youtube api in delphi

Tags: javascript, delphi, youtube-api, delphi-7

I'm trying to execute a javascript that has youtube api to the WebBrowser1.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'test.html');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Doc: IHTMLDocument2;      // current HTML document
  HTMLWindow: IHTMLWindow2; // parent window of current HTML document
  JSFn: string;
begin
  // Get reference to current document
  Doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  if not Assigned(Doc) then
    Exit;
  // Get parent window of current document
  HTMLWindow := Doc.parentWindow;
  if not Assigned(HTMLWindow) then
    Exit;
  // Run JavaScript
  try
    JSFn := 'onYouTubePlayerAPIReady()';
    HTMLWindow.execScript(JSFn, 'JavaScript');
  except
    on E : Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.ClassName+' error raised, with message : '+E.Message);  //error EOleException, 80020101
  end;
end;
```

but this raised an error : EOleException, 80020101

Here is my test.html

```
<div id="player"></div>
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script>

        // create youtube player
        var player;
        function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', { //<-- error
              height: '390',
              width: '640',
              videoId: '0Bmhjf0rKe8',
              events: {
                  'onReady': onPlayerReady
                  }
            });
        }


        // autoplay video
        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.playVideo();
        }

</script>
```

Here I want to embed the video to WebBrowser1 and then auto play it using the javascript that has youtube api.

Is this possible to make this work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the [Youtube javascript player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference), which is deprecated. You must use the [Youtube Iframe player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). If you have the HTML under control, then there is no need for special code on the delphi side.

Here is a complete and working example:

HTML code (is the same code from the YT API reference page, I just added the autoplay variable):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- // this is needed to force our embedded browser to run in EDGE mode -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>

      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0 }, // this is essential for autoplay
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Delphi code:

```
unit u_frm_main;

interface

uses
  MsHtml,
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.OleCtrls, SHDocVw;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'test.html');
end;

end.
```